# My RandomForestRegressor Predictive Model gets repetitive

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

***Data***

I have this data that shows Year, Month, and Customers Count

```
Yr      Mth Cnt
2004    7   8966
2004    8   9564
2004    9   9324
2004    10  9895
2004    11  9689
2004    12  10358
2005    1   9955
2005    2   8840
2005    3   10076
2005    4   9827
2005    5   10710
2005    6   10356
2005    7   10689
2005    8   10772
2005    9   10003
2005    10  10655
2005    11  10360
2005    12  11093
2006    1   10874
2006    2   9616
2006    3   10908
2006    4   10524
2006    5   10602
2006    6   10273
2006    7   11247
2006    8   11072
2006    9   10285
2006    10  11236
2006    11  10702
2006    12  11138
2007    1   10695
2007    2   10040
2007    3   11254
2007    4   11372
2007    5   11630
2007    6   10890
2007    7   11221
2007    8   12411
2007    9   11129
2007    10  10620
2007    11  11078
2007    12  11553
2008    1   10614
2008    2   10235
2008    3   11216
2008    4   10690
2008    5   11214
2008    6   11042
2008    7   10722
2008    8   11216
2008    9   11234
2008    10  10907
2008    11  10628
2008    12  11382
2009    1   10789
2009    2   9908
2009    3   11387
2009    4   10805
2009    5   12096
2009    6   11937
2009    7   11358
2009    8   11490
2009    9   10836
2009    10  11899
2009    11  11565
2009    12  11874
2010    1   11030
2010    2   10488
2010    3   12017
2010    4   11412
2010    5   11990
2010    6   11216
2010    7   11728
2010    8   12131
2010    9   11603
2010    10  12105
2010    11  12152
2010    12  12360
2011    1   11940
2011    2   10739
2011    3   12153
2011    4   11665
2011    5   11886
2011    6   11720
2011    7   11625
2011    8   12257
2011    9   11582
2011    10  11661
2011    11  11437
2011    12  12146
2012    1   11375
2012    2   11228
2012    3   12164
2012    4   11801
2012    5   12058
2012    6   11929
2012    7   12107
2012    8   11728
2012    9   11816
2012    10  11918
2012    11  11835
2012    12  12500
2013    1   11733
2013    2   10916
2013    3   12262
2013    4   11658
2013    5   12357
2013    6   12000
2013    7   11911
2013    8   12353
2013    9   11772
2013    10  11671
2013    11  11546
2013    12  12228
2014    1   11886
2014    2   10985
2014    3   12777
2014    4   11613
2014    5   12358
2014    6   12227
2014    7   12032
2014    8   12800
2014    9   12299
2014    10  12693
2014    11  12520
2014    12  13243
2015    1   12459
2015    2   11998
2015    3   13234
2015    4   12492
2015    5   13081
2015    6   12968
2015    7   12572
2015    8   13475
2015    9   12301
2015    10  13167
2015    11  12885
2015    12  13498
2016    1   12807
2016    2   12904
2016    3   13689
2016    4   13318
2016    5   13813
2016    6   13083
2016    7   13309
2016    8   13688
2016    9   13231
2016    10  13570
2016    11  14195
2016    12  14798
2017    1   13762
2017    2   12839
2017    3   14542
2017    4   13631
2017    5   14640
2017    6   14371
2017    7   14350
2017    8   14725
2017    9   14362
2017    10  14605
2017    11  14174
2017    12  14243
2018    1   13636
2018    2   13099
2018    3   14313
2018    4   13632
2018    5   14284
2018    6   13676
2018    7   13708
2018    8   14018
2018    9   13716
2018    10  14283
2018    11  13902
2018    12  14753
2019    1   14075
2019    2   13369
2019    3   14774
2019    4   13919
2019    5   13715
```

Which clearly has incline over the time

This is a yearly figure that shows increase in the number every year

[image]

at the same time in the monthly figure you can see that Feb has a drop in the number of the customers every year

[image]

***Code***

As data is not 100% inclining I thought LinearRegression is not the right model as it does not show the drop in Feb in the future predictions

I used RandomTreeRegressor

Here is My code

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor


conn = pymssql.connect(server="SalesServer", database="Customers")
df = pd.read_sql("EXEC SP_CustomersCount", conn)
conn.close()

#a new column i have created to make data continious
df["YrMth"] = (12 * (df["Yr"] - 2000)) + df["Mth"]


x_test = pd.read_csv(r"c:\temp\MonthlyPred.csv")

#a new column i have created to make data continious
x_test["YrMth"] = (12 * (x_test["Yr"] - 2000)) + x_test["Mth"]

x= df.drop("Cnt", axis=1)
y= df["Cnt"]

x_train = x
y_train = y


rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
rf.fit(x_train, y_train) 
y_pred = rf.predict(x_test)

y_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred)            

print(x_test.assign( Pred= y_pred.iloc[:,0]))
```

**Results**

I get these predictions

```
    Yr      Mth YrMth Pred
0   2019    5    233  13872.707
1   2019    6    234  13867.611
2   2019    7    235  13879.211
3   2019    8    236  13970.375
4   2019    9    237  13961.416
5   2019   10    238  14121.583
6   2019   11    239  14107.296
7   2019   12    240  14430.914
8   2020    1    241  13893.945
9   2020    2    242  13529.786
10  2020    3    243  14335.714
11  2020    4    244  13933.575
12  2020    5    245  13872.707
13  2020    6    246  13867.611
14  2020    7    247  13879.211
15  2020    8    248  13970.375
16  2020    9    249  13961.416
17  2020   10    250  14121.583
18  2020   11    251  14107.296
19  2020   12    252  14430.914
20  2021    1    253  13893.945
21  2021    2    254  13529.786
22  2021    3    255  14335.714
23  2021    4    256  13933.575
24  2021    5    257  13872.707
25  2021    6    258  13867.611
26  2021    7    259  13879.211
27  2021    8    260  13970.375
28  2021    9    261  13961.416
29  2021   10    262  14121.583
30  2021   11    263  14107.296
31  2021   12    264  14430.914
32  2022    1    265  13893.945
33  2022    2    266  13529.786
34  2022    3    267  14335.714
35  2022    4    268  13933.575
36  2022    5    269  13872.707
37  2022    6    270  13867.611
38  2022    7    271  13879.211
39  2022    8    272  13970.375
40  2022    9    273  13961.416
41  2022   10    274  14121.583
42  2022   11    275  14107.296
43  2022   12    276  14430.914
44  2023    1    277  13893.945
45  2023    2    278  13529.786
46  2023    3    279  14335.714
47  2023    4    280  13933.575
48  2023    5    281  13872.707
49  2023    6    282  13867.611
50  2023    7    283  13879.211
51  2023    8    284  13970.375
52  2023    9    285  13961.416
53  2023   10    286  14121.583
54  2023   11    287  14107.296
55  2023   12    288  14430.914
```

which are clearly not right as the same amounts get repeated every year for the same month (May 2019 same as May 2020, same as 2021, etc)

the ideal solution should show incline yearly and drop in Feb

***My Question***

My understanding is RandomForestRegressor use Tree decision then build regression 
Why is that happening?

***Expectation***

Am I doing anything wrong here?
Is that the right model?

Comment: A random forest model should ideally be able to pick up on and predict the drop in sales in February.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It pick up the drop in Feb, but predictions are repeatative every year Feb 2020 = Feb 2021 = Feb 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the model
I used Auto-Sklearn

I got better results

Answer (score -1):

what form is the x_test given in?

you can't do all the years at once because the nn need the data of the previous year in order to accurately predict

so I think you need to feed it the data that it outputs.

I'm not sure if that is right cos I don't know that x_train and x_test are. Are they the dates or something else? I tried to do that but I couldn't access the dataset as it 'failed for unknown reason'

I hope it helps :)